# What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?

Tags: support, faq-proposed, community-bulletin, featured-tag

On [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), there are two posts from the meta site shown on the *Community Bulletin* is, at moment I am writing this question.

Previously, there was just a single meta post linked from that block, and it was a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) post; the total number of links was the same, as there was also a link to a blog.

> [image: screenshot]

What are the criteria used to show the links in that block? Do the links to blog posts or event posts have the priority?

For example, there were new posts on the front page, and the second question linked from the block is actually the 41st question shown on the front page.

> [image: screenshot]

Now that the event expired, this is what the block shows, in different moments of the same day. (The screenshots have been taken at a distance of not more than 2 hours.)

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: (As an aside: more general info about it in [New Community Bulletin box in side area](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129483/new-community-bulletin-box-in-side-area), but you being a moderator on Drupal I guess its answers about some "Mod Links menu" are not about what you're asking now? And the old "featured" thingy was [explained by Jeff in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128531/the-moderator-tag-featured-must-be-present-but-it-wasnt-there-in-the-first/128533#comment351031_128533) to another post.)

Comment: I am interested in how the automatically added links are added/handled. I see moderators are able to add new events (and in this case, there is just an event added from a Stack Exchange's employee). In this case there is a link about a blog post, and two links about meta posts; it is not clear to me in which way those two links are selected, and what the criteria for showing blog/meta post links is.

Comment: The name "Community Bulletin" is no longer used, but the box is still referred to by that name. Those keywords were there so that people searching for any of those newer terms would find this question.

Comment: @Sonic Which keywords? The question has already a very specific tag. I have not seen "keywords" added to questions about old features not implemented nowadays.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The rules are as follows:

- If there is a community moderator **election**, [a link to it appears in the bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111673/create-a-permanent-link-to-the-electionarea-during-electiontime/132331#132331).
- **Events** can be created with a start date and time, an end date and time, a simple title, and a link to something somewhere on the network. Current or upcoming events are listed, with those starting or ending nearest to the current time shown first.
- If there are fewer than four items listed, blog posts from [the Stack Exchange blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/) are added to the list, under the heading **The Overflow Blog**. A maximum of two posts will be shown, and only those posted in the past *n* days, where *n* is currently 10 on International versions of Stack Overflow, and 5 everywhere else. The particular blog posts eligible for selection on a site [depend on what tags the blog posts use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343846/377214).
- If there are still fewer than four total items listed, then (non-closed) per-site meta posts tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) are linked; these are termed **Featured**.
- If there are still under four total items, the rest of the space is filled with **Hot Meta Posts**: semi-randomly-selected questions from the [hot tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/377214) on the per-site meta, which meet the following criteria:

  - Be tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
  - Not be tagged with any moderator status tag
  - Scoring at least 3
  - Have been posted in the past two weeks
  - Not have been [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353492/377214) from Hot Meta Posts by a moderator

  Note that the exact criteria [can be adjusted per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community.

At least two featured questions or Hot Meta Posts (combined, not each) will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4 (so long as there are enough).

**Additionally**, up to two non-closed [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeatured%5D+is%3Aquestion+created%3A14d..) will appear in the community bulletins of *all* network sites (including Meta Stack Exchange, but not per-site metas). These are also filed under "Featured". Note that these will appear in addition to all of the other stuff listed above, so the list of community bulletin posts might appear longer than usual, depending on the individual site circumstances.

The URLs are checked at each stage to prevent [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131390/dont-show-meta-posts-that-are-also-linked-as-community-bulletins) items from being displayed (so that, for instance, a hot discussion post with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag linked to a scheduled event won't ever fill 3 of the 4 slots). Items are considered identical if the URL and Title match *or* if they both point to the same question or answer on any Stack Exchange site (so that changing the title of a hot meta post linked from a scheduled event won't inadvertently result in it appearing twice).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there an explanation about why the Community Bulletin passes from showing only the [meta-tag:featured] post, to showing more posts, and then back to showing only the [meta-tag:featured] post? I noticed that in the past days, and I don't understand why it happens, if there are already posts matching the required criteria.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: is this still happening? It could be a factor of how the hot algorithm works, or it could be a bug in the logic that picks questions from that list.

Comment: I noticed it also recently. I should check again when blog entries are not shown. Should I ask a question just for that, if I see that happening again?

Comment: @kiam: this should be fixed now.

Comment: Is this still how it works? The CB on [Board and Card Games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions) only seems to have one item at present, an ordinary meta post...

Comment: @ire_and_curses: yup. B&CG doesn't have a very active meta - only two recent questions, only one meeting this criteria.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the algorithm carefully enough. Got it, thanks!

Comment: Does closed Q's apply into the algorithm?

Comment: So, now we would not have a warranty that there would be at least 1 hot meta post?

Comment: I'm not sure there was ever a warranty of that, @Braiam; these rules were originally the spec for the implementation, but I recently revised them to match the actual implementation - I don't know off-hand when the implementation diverged from the original spec, but the actual behavior for quite some time has been "always link at least one hot or featured meta post" without regard to which source.

Comment: Exactly, but now the specs read as "there will not be hot meta post if featured and or blogs use the 4 available spots", which diverge from the historic behavior that you describe ("there will be at least 1 hot meta post even if we have to go over 4 items") as [it was reported a couple times as a not fulfilled promise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336870).

Comment: You misunderstand me, @Braiam. I'm saying it hasn't worked that way for a long time; I'm not entirely sure it ever worked that way [**Edit:** I looked up the revision history of the code in question - it never worked that way]. This post exists to document the behavior of the bulletin - originally, that information was drawn from the spec, but given that wasn't accurate I updated it to reflect the actual implementation.