# Don't show Meta posts that are also linked as Community Bulletins

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-bulletin

UX is planning a Hackathon and we've created a community event for it, and linked the relevant meta post. However, the Meta post now shows up twice in the Bulletin, once as a popular meta post, once as a bulletin.

The meta post is the Event link and the second Meta link as well.

[image]

It'd be cool if the Bulletin was smart enough to not show the Meta post as a separate item so more space could be used for other, unique meta posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed – the Community Bulletin should no longer contain multiple items with the same url.

For example, if an **event** already links to

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131390`

and a would-be featured **meta post** is

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131390/dont-show-meta-posts-that-are-also-linked-as-community-bulletins`

then the event will take precedence and the meta post won't be included in the bulletin.