# Community Bulletin duplicates links

Tags: feature-request, bug, moderator-tools, community-bulletin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't show Meta posts that are also linked as Community Bulletins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131390/dont-show-meta-posts-that-are-also-linked-as-community-bulletins)

On the [Movies & TV Site](http://movies.stackexchange.com), we posted a couple of events that were of community importance.  Since we only have two events going on the Community Bulletin picked up our two most active meta posts.  These just so happen to be the same posts that were put up as events.  It would be nice if the Community Bulletin would detect duplicate posts.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that both the Meta posts you've linked the bulletin events to are 'Featured' posts as well?

[Featured meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board) are also a criteria for displaying on the bulletin. If you remove the featured tag then you *should* reduce the chance of those posts also showing up on the bulletin (although if they're still highly popular meta posts they may still appear, but at least you can reduce the probability of this happening by untagging them as featured).

Comment: Aye this is true, though removing the "featured" tag seems counter-productive (assumingly, though I suppose 'featured' was originally meant for the sidebar) as one is our beta eval and the other is an important FAQ issue.