# What is the difference between the per-site metas' FAQ and Featured tags?

Tags: discussion, site-faq, community-bulletin, featured-tag

With the introduction of the new Community Bulletin, I'm finding myself confused between the purpose of the red [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag and the red [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on the per-site metas.

[image: Sidebar with Community Bulletin]

In the above sidebar, in the Community Bulletin, one of the questions listed has the tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and the other has the tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).

In the tag wikis on the meta sites, the featured tag is described as a special moderator-only tag that is used to highlight important discussions and display them on the main page. I get this, but the FAQ tag is somewhat unclear as it seems to do the very same thing that the featured tag does.

**FAQ Tag Wiki:**

> These questions are the most frequently asked and answered questions on Meta.

So how should the FAQ tag be used? My initial thought was to use it to highlight important information that the community should consider adding to the site's FAQ, or to use it to keep track of discussions or questions that support what is listed in the FAQ already, but I'm not sure this is the correct usage.

Also, should the Community Bulletin board display these questions differently, perhaps by displaying which tag is used to place the question on the main site?

Are questions with these two tags handled differently on the Community Bulletin board or are they treated the same?

**NOTE:**  Sorry about the sloppy handwriting. I think I gave myself carpal-tunnel trying to use Ubuntu to annotate a screenshot.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined

Comment: I don't think the faq tack stickies to the bulletin, while Featured does

Comment: @BenBrocka - Just to clarify, by "faq tag stickies to the bulletin" you mean it appears temporarily but then eventually drops off? Because it would be wrong to say it doesn't appear at all in the Community Bulletin. Sorry, just want to seek clarity so no one is confused ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that FAQ question only showed up because it's a highly upvoted discussion quesiton, another criteria for showing up on there

Comment: @BenBrocka - Oh ok, good to know! Makes sense. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the official view, but judging from my experience:

The [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is used for important discussions, related to the FAQ or not. Anything important for the site should have this tag. This tag expires after a bit, so make sure to keep it under control. After all, you don't want too many important discussions being "opened" at the same time.

The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) instead, is for issues and questions that are frequently asked in the Meta site and therefore deserve the tag. It could also be for subjects/stuff not covered by the site's main FAQ. I think this one doesn't expire.

- Example of FAQ tag's usage on Meta SE:  [Meta SE FAQ Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- Example of FAQ tag's usage on Programmers SE Meta:  [Meta Programmers SE FAQ Tag](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)

Perhaps the main difference is that the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag is linked in the bottom of FAQ entries on MSE. Questions with the [meta-faq](/questions/tagged/meta-faq) tag are for posts that are an extension of the FAQ.

Comment: That was sort of my understanding too, but I couldn't find any documentation anywhere and wanted to see if anything has changed since the Community Bulletin introduction. Also, just looked at your post and now see how to get the tags to appear without having to take screenshots of them lol. `[meta-tag:featured]`

Comment: Not quite. [meta-tag:faq] is not *about* the site's FAQ. It's for questions that are frequently asked on meta, perhaps stuff that's not actually covered by the general FAQ page. Check out how it's used here on MSO, for example.

Comment: Should I include that in my answer, @AnnaLear?

Comment: @Alenanno Sure. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - Looking at how it's used here on Meta does help somewhat in that the questions are not about specific scenarios but instead more broad topics. I'm thinking then that questions tagged [meta-tag:faq] should basically act as a single repository of information based on the combined answers of other, more specific meta questions that relate to the topic in general. Also, is Alenanno correct about the non-expiring feature of the FAQ tag?

Comment: @jmort253 Around here it ends up being used for things that apply to the network in general. On SE 2.0 sites it's often more about site-specific stuff. Here's another example from Programmers meta: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

Comment: @AnnaLear - Again, that's very helpful. Thank you for the examples!

Comment: @jmort253 We also have a [FAQ Index](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/faq-index-for-programmers-se), that has all our Meta FAQ questions categorized and also points to some of the more useful blog posts.

Comment: @YannisRizos - Thank you! I added this to the answer as well since it's a great example. :)

Comment: I don't know that we've ever come up with a formal "official view" for this distinction, but this looks good to me.