# Should [featured] posts be showing up as such in the community bulletin?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

A question on my site's meta is currently [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) - it's [this one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3297/1204). From memory, featured posts used to show up with "featured" in the left column, but it's just showing up as another "meta" item:

[image: nothing 'featured']

Am I remembering correctly? If so, did something change, or is it a bug that this question isn't showing up that way?

Comment: That's true enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Community Bulletin was [redesigned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234453/redesigned-community-bulletin), they are actually shown as such.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was just my imagination. [Several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137928/152515) [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133704/152515) [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/152515) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135655/152515) about the community bulletin on here mention featured questions, but they all just have 'meta' in the sidebar.