# Community Bulletin only showing Events, not Meta posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin

Some time recently the Community Bulletin stopped showing Meta posts:

UX:

[image]

CogSci:

[image]

[According to SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/166936) discussions and featured meta posts should be in there (and were, last I checked before now) so that it always shows 4 items. It doesn't show up right on Main or Meta for any site I've checked.

The bulletin is just *gone* on Workplace where there are no events. All of these sites have [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tags and meta discussions so they should be full.

Comment: In other news, the community bulletin looks friggin' *weird* without that yellow background.

Comment: @Shog9 yeah I'm not quite sure I like how it looks on UX...but I'd like it less if it was a glowing yellow postit note on the side of the page in UX's theme

Comment: [Repo'd on Movies.SE](http://i.imgur.com/0PuxV.png)

Comment: Oh so something *was* going on... For a moment I thought the `featured` tags expired all at once lol. It's happening on [Linguistics SE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kkIh9.png) and [Chinese SE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ud5E.png) too.

Comment: @Alenanno even if the tags expired you'd see non-featured meta posts on there

Comment: I thought the mods did that, but it's happening on Programmers also.

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes you're right, you mean the hot discussions, right? I did think it was weird. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a short blog outage which has been resolved.  This appears to impact the community bulletin as well.  The cache will clear and display correctly within the hour.