# Where has the community bulletin gone?

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

Is it just me or has the community bulletin (i.e. hot meta posts, featured posts etc.) for Stack Overflow vanished? It appears to still be around on other sites.

[image]

Comment: Oh the CB played a lot of Hide and Seek last year on Stack Overflow http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts

Comment: @BhargavRao Indeed, in fact I even [commented](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312035/what-happened-to-the-hot-meta-posts#comment281277_312035) on that one :)

Comment: @Oded there is a featured question on MSO. Answer here is wrong. No bulletin means that there was a bug. (Now it's there, but it will go away again as nothing is fixed)

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s not just you.

There is nothing wrong either, however. Right now, there simply is no [featured Meta post](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) or [recent blog post](//stackoverflow.blog/feed/).

On sites which have hot or featured posts on their per-site Meta, you can see it right now, e.g., [here](//academia.stackexchange.com/) or [here](//german.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The [rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/261748) for what goes in the CB state that *If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with hot discussion questions not marked [meta-tag:status-completed], scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks.* So... where are the hot meta posts?

Comment: @DavidG: On Meta SE, there never were hot Meta posts. On other per-site metas, it still works (see my edit).

Comment: OK, bad screenshot to use as an example perhaps, but it is also missing on Stackoverflow and we *do* have hot posts there.

Comment: @DavidG: Then, it’s probably an SO-specific problem, since it seems to work on every other page.

Comment: Yeah that may be the case, I almost posted on MSO rather than here.

Comment: Also, I cannot see the CB on those 2 sites you linked to? (the hot network posts list is not the same a the community bulletin)

Comment: @DavidG: Hmm, that’s probably because you do not have an account on these sites.

Comment: It seems to be back now anyway!

Comment: "there simply is no featured Meta post" - Wrong. MSO got featured question, just checked and it wasn't unfeatured today.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: When I wrote this answer, the question was about Meta Stack **Exchange**.

Comment: Oh. Well, the answer is not relevant anymore in such a case. (and question should be closed and re-asked on MSO.) /cc @David

Comment: @shadowwizard well its entirely possible that the issue affected multiple sites but there's no way to tell because (as far as I can see) there's no list of sites that opt in/out of it (or even if that's possible outside of MSE). Don't think it's worse reasking on MSO tbh.

Comment: @David I don't think there's any option, even for dev or CM, to turn off the bulletin for specific site. And looks like it's misbehaving only on SO, maybe due to the traffic, or amount of questions on the meta site.