# "Featured on meta" in community bulletin not updating

Tags: support, caching, community-bulletin, featured-tag

Not sure if this is just excessive caching, or something else: We had two meta items tagged as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) but [only the original item](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/) is displaying. 11 hours ago we remove the tag from the original item, but it's still showing and the newer item is still not showing.

[image: Incorrect featured on meta items]

According to [these rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/33051) we should be able to have two [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) items on the community bulletin?

Am I being too impatient? When I tagged the first item it appeared almost immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this is caching.

I invalidated the bulletin cache and the new post is coming up now.

Comment: Cheers - was it supposed to be that heavily cached though?

Comment: Different parts of the bulletin come from different places, and for cross site data access (such as between a site and its meta), we do cache quite heavily.