# Old featured meta question intermittently appearing in "Featured on Meta" box

Tags: bug, sidebar, featured-tag

For some reason, a Meta question on IPS has recently erroneously appeared in the sidebar "Featured on Meta" box. Not only is this question *not* currently featured, it's locked. The featured tag was removed February 2nd, and this is not a caching issue because it *was not* in the box earlier this evening.

Some screenshots:

#### The box and the entirety of the currently tagged "featured" list.

> [image: Only one featured question, two featured in sidebar]

#### The history page that shows the featured tag being removed on February 2nd and locked.

[image: History page with tag being removed and question being locked]

Why must I be forced to relive out past failures???

My understanding is that this occurs from time to time. How can it be fixed? There's a similar problem on PPCG and, interestingly, that post is also locked for historical significance. I'm not sure if that's part of the bug or merely a coincidence.

Can we please fix this?

---

It's been a month. It's March 2nd and I'm still seeing it posted in the sidebar. At the same time, I have unfeatured the "UPDATED: COMPLETED" post in the first image (which is not locked) and it is not being affected.

Comment: Fine... fix it the same exact instant I post the question... even though I waited to check the meta sidebar before posting it...

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290606/featured-on-meta-in-community-bulletin-not-updating and you'll need a dev / CM to kick some servers

Comment: Very much related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297870/post-remains-featured-even-if-featured-tag-is-removed (might be the same issue, not sure enough to close as dupe though.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That seems more similar. I don't know whether it's been appearing all week. I only noticed it last night. But it shares many of the same symptoms.

Comment: @Catija maybe it was out while there was something else there, e.g. other featured question, or blog post?

Comment: Looks like it's the lock then, which locks the question in featured state. Since most likely they won't fix this bug any time soon (more urgent things to do, optimistic hope is several months to one year) better unlock the question, maybe add then remove again the featured tag to kick it out the sidebar.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Seems reasonable to me... except someone with much more experience than I have said that they've seen it happen with posts that aren't locked.

Comment: That was most likely cache, which can be aggressive, e.g. take hours until it's synchronized, but not forever like with locked questions. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well.. I've tried... Now I'll see if it comes back.

Comment: ... and it has. So, that's a no-go.