# How much does community bulletin add to visibility of the question?

Tags: discussion, support, per-site-meta, statistics, community-bulletin

It seems that posts on meta which are displayed in community bulletin get more views than other posts. Of course, this could have many reasons. (Maybe the discussions were interesting enough to generate many views - independently of being displayed in CB. Probably many users use CB simply as a quick way to get to meta, etc.) However, this is based only on my *personal observations* - which is not always reliable source. (If nothing else, nobody is immune to [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias).) So it might be interesting to know some official statistics about this.

**Question.** Is it possible to get some statistics about number of views generated though community bulletin compared to views coming from elsewhere?

I suppose that Stack Exchange has some internal tracking system. If I visit a questions by clicking on it in the community bulletin, I always see `?cb=1` attached at the end of the url. I suppose this is exactly for this purpose. (A possible alternative would be some SEDE query comparing, for example, average number of views for questions [eligible for CB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/what-criteria-is-used-to-select-the-links-that-appear-in-the-community-bulletin) with other questions. However, this would be probably much less reliable for many reasons. And it is not immediately clear what would be good way to compare them.)

Comment: I've just (6-8 weeks ago) started to track # of views for HNQs. If I'd realize this question would've come up, I'd had probably tracked it as well. But maybe the `?cb=1` will allow a friendly Shog to provide (better) data from the analytics tool.