# Is there a list of all historical Hot Meta Posts across the network?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

Since [August 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353492/295232), questions which become Hot Meta Posts and are visible in the site's Community Bulletin, get an event in their timeline indicating this. Is it possible to view which questions have become 'hot' during a certain period?

Comment: Please explain why this would be useful to know. Yes, curiosity is a strong contender and I realise that nerds love this type of data, but how can this feature be *useful*? What will happen to the results in two year's time? I can well envision an avalanche of data.

Comment: -1 for the "historical" in the title (it's misleading and a bit clickbaity) we are currently in August 2020.

Comment: @Mari-LouA E.g., data about post which were in the community bulletin could be useful to check what is average viewcount for those questions compared to all questions or questions which did not enter CB. Since community feedback on some meta discussions is important, I would consider such data useful, since we could get some insight into which questions get visited often and which are mostly ignored by the users (and to which extent CB is a factor). In fact, here is my older question: [How much does community bulletin add to visibility of the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321278)

Comment: @Martin you have view counts for that reason, no need to pull up a SEDE query. But what do I know?! I ain't a programmer.  If Glorfindel edits their post, I'll reverse the downvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, thanks to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) this is possible. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1287917/hot-meta-posts-networkwide?fromDate=2020-08-20&tillDate=2021-12-31) shows when a question was posted, when it became a Hot Meta Post and (if applicable) when it was manually removed from the list.

[image]

Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.