# Allow local mods to remove items from community bulletin

Tags: feature-request, moderators, community-bulletin

Community bulletin might contain various items which are "network-wide". I mean blog posts and featured questions from Meta Stack Exchange.<sup>1</sup> Depending on the site, some of them might be less interesting to the users of the specific site.

- They might be about issue unrelated to the site. (For example, the recent announcement that 29 sites are no longer in beta - this is probably less interesting for users of graduated sites.)
- Some of them are added mainly with intention of getting some aspect of SE better known or maybe some entertainment value (such as introducing a new employee) and are not of big importance to the local community.
- Sometimes there might be several important issues being discussed on a per-site-meta at the same time, in such cases the posts from Meta Stack Exchange might take attention from them. (Although posts from Meta Stack Exchange actually cannot push local posts from the community bulletin,<sup>2</sup> the fact that they are displayed at the top make them more noticeable and takes some attention away from the "local" hot meta posts.)

**Proposal.** Add a possibility for the moderators to remove blog posts or hot Meta Stack Exchange question from the "local" community bulletin (i.e, on a per-site basis).

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless I missed something, other types of entries in the community bulletin have some relation to the site on which they are displayed: [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621)

<sup>2</sup>Quote from the above post ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/130893/17)): "**Additionally**, up to two [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeatured%5D+is%3Aquestion+created%3A14d..) will appear in the community bulletins of *all* main sites (but no child meta sites). These are also labeled "meta". Note that these will appear in addition to all of the other stuff listed above, so the list of community bulletin posts might appear longer than usual, depending on the individual site circumstances."

Answer (score 1):

Is it really the content that's the issue or the duration?

Some graduated site users might not care about the beta announcement, but other people are involved in multiple sites, some of which may have just come out of beta.  I think the bigger issue with the announcement is that it's been featured since [August 3rd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/331708/revisions), which if I recall correctly, is the maximum duration a topic can be featured (30 days).  And that's a fairly long time to have an announcement pinned at the top of every site bulletin.

Most other announcements tend to be much shorter-lived.  The podcast ones linger for a while, but those are actually discussing how the community team feels about the network and you can get an idea on how the company would like those sites to grow and develop.  That said, I imagine most people that are interested listen on the first week even though the announcement lingers until the next podcast episode.

As you said in your post, the featured posts from Meta Stack Exchange don't consume any slots from the local community, they just sit above them.

So if posts were just broadcast to all sites for a shorter duration (let's say a week at most), would there still be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the 1st and 2nd points for now, looks like the core of the issue is the 3rd point:

> Sometimes there might be several important issues being discussed on a per-site-meta at the same time, in such cases the posts from Meta Stack Exchange might take attention from them.

If it's the case, then isn't a better compromise is to **change the order by putting all per-site related posts on the top** instead? Following the [guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893), it will look like:

1. Election
2. Events
3. Featured on Meta (local site)
4. Hot Meta Posts
5. Blog posts
6. Featured on Meta (Meta SE)

---

Back to the 1st and 2nd point,

> They might be about issue unrelated to the site.
>
> Some of them are added mainly with intention of getting some aspect of SE better known or maybe some entertainment value (such as introducing a new employee).

While both of these may be unrelated to the site, basically, they are **official posts/announcements by the company** (AFAIK, local MSE mods still don't have permission to add/remove [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag yet). It's not about *the* local site but the bigger SE network, in which the local site is *also* the part of it:

1. The "29 graduated sites" is a moving point from the strict "10 questions/day" criteria for beta sites. It's moot for graduated sites, but kind of relieving for *every user* (regardless from beta/graduated sites) who want to propose a new site and afraid of getting it stuck in a perpetual beta.
2. The discussion in "Unicorn Meta Zoo" is mostly applicable to every SE site.
3. Introducing a new employee, especially a [Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/241919), is *very* important, because they are the one who will mostly interact with your site on meta.

---

In the end, they are basically news. Those who don't want to read can just ignore them, but that doesn't mean that everyone don't want to read them...

Comment: +1 for the suggestions to change order of items.

Comment: No, to me the main issue is not the order, it's the fact that SE is starting to misuse this feature for self-serving announcements like "meet our new staff employee" or "listen to our new podcast" that are of no interest to me. These are on the same level of obnoxiousness as ads, in my personal scale.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni it is of no interest to you personally, not to the whole community. This feature request is asking on site-level though, not personal level.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I agree with you that the problem is "what is considered interesting for the community"; that's why I pointed out that the main issue is not the ordering of these items. Simply put, this question suggests that the moderators (that we elected) are more qualified than the SE staff to decide what is, or is not, interesting for each site community. Personally, I agree.