# Question tagged (featured) and (status-completed) not shown in the community bulletin

Tags: bug, community-bulletin, featured-tag

I have noticed that the question "[An info box to point new users to The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18028)" on Code Golf Meta is tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), yet it is not shown in the community bulletin. (I have added screenshots below.) The featured tag was included already [when the question was posted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/18028/revisions), so it's not a matter of caching.

It seems quite likely that the reason might that there is also the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag. (I have tried to find whether there is some question with the combination of these two tags on another meta, but I did not find one.)

However, this is not how the composition of community bulletin is explained here: [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621#130893) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/130893/17)). No exception is mentioned in the part about featured posts: "If there are still fewer than four items listed, then **[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts** are shown." The (status-completed) tag is only mentioned in the next bullet point - about hot meta post from the local meta.

**Question.** Is this really caused by the presence of the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag? Is this intended behavior or a bug?

If this is how the community bulletin is supposed to behave, the information in the linked post should be updated. (And if not, well, then it's a bug.)

This is what I see in the community bulletin on the main site:

[image: screenshot of the community bulletin]

And this is how it looks on meta:

[image: screenshot of the community bulletin]