# Why are different blog articles featured on different sites?

Tags: discussion, blog, community-bulletin

On [sustainability.se](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/), [skeptics.se](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), and several others, I see:

[image: Community working group updates, February 2020]

On [electronics.se](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), [engineering.se](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), [so](https://stackoverflow.com/), and several others, I see:

[image: Podcast: Coaching a Developer Interview; Trying to find your first dev job? Here's what employers are actually looking...]

My best guess is that it has to do with the audience of the site -- Stack Overflow and more "technically" oriented sites have the dev-focused blog articles featured, while everybody else gets the more meta-oriented blog articles.

Comment: Maybe it's only possible to see 2 featured posts at a time?

Comment: Added a bounty - it's a bit unclear that it actually works the way it is described in the accepted answer. (Or at least what happens if none of the tags mentioned there is present.) For example, [Find knowledge faster: New Articles features](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/03/find-knowledge-faster-new-articles-features/) is only tagged company and it is shown [on many sites](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2021/5/8). Similarly the post about Webby Awards was shared [on various sites](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2021/4/30) and it wasn't tagged announcement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's tag-dependent.

- Blog posts tagged "bulletin" appear in the sidebar on sites that are considered technology sites (based on the sites listed in the footer) but not on others.
- Blog posts tagged "announcements" appear everywhere on the network (except on international sites).
- There's a third for "stack-overflow" which only appears on Stack Overflow unless it also has one of the other two tags.
- We also have an "international" tag for blog posts written in other languages and that can be paired with a language tag to cause the post to appear on the Russian, Spanish, Portuguese or Japanese SO sites

The bulletin only shows two blog posts at a time and it prefers the most recent. This is why you don't see the "Community working groups updates" post on the technology sites - there are newer blogs that have been featured.

Comment: Ah, so this explains it, I thought that the different posts were showing far too long for [it to be caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/). The [announcements tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/announcements/) does however contain lots of posts which are tech focused and not announcements. :(

Comment: Why is the [dev survey post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/19/new-decade-new-survey-goals-reminder-to-take-the-survey-before-it-closes-next-week/?cb=1) shown on non-tech sites?

Comment: It has the "announcements" tag... or are you asking why it has announcement instead of bulletin?

Comment: The latter. I know the survey is a big deal in SO's year, but if there's meant to be a system I'd hope it would be followed more consistently. It's not worth following up on though.

Comment: What happens if none of those tags is used in the blog post? For example, "[Vote for Stack Overflow in this year’s Webby Awards!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/29/vote-for-stack-overflow-in-this-years-webby-awards/)" is tagged only [webby award](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/webby-award/) and it is shown in CB on various sites. (Screenshot can be seen in [this feature request](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4339) on MathOverflow Meta.)