# On all sites, the bulletin incorrectly displays certain blog posts for up to a week even if they're ineligible to appear on the site due to their tags

Tags: support, blog, community-bulletin

[This blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/?cb=1) is currently featured on all network sites' community bulletins. As per [this staff post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343846/256282), only those posts that have the announcements tag are supposed to be featured across the network:

> - Blog posts tagged "bulletin" appear in the sidebar on sites that are considered technology sites (based on the sites listed in the footer) but not on others.
> - Blog posts tagged "announcements" appear everywhere on the network (except on international sites).
> - There's a third for "stack-overflow" which only appears on Stack Overflow unless it also has one of the other two tags.
> - We also have an "international" tag for blog posts written in other languages and that can be paired with a language tag to cause the post to appear on the Russian, Spanish, Portuguese or Japanese SO sites

The post doesn't have *any* of the tags that would result in it being featured on any subset of sites in the network. The post has one category at the top, "community", and three tags at the bottom, "april fools", "copying code", and "data science".

Why is this blog post featured on all sites, even though it doesn't have the tag "announcements" or any of the tags mentioned in the above quote? Was the announcements tag mistakenly added on initial publication but removed later?

---

**Update:** I've seen some other blog posts that show up on all sites' community bulletins even if they don't have any tags that'd result in syndication. As an example, [this blog post published August 30, 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/30/the-full-data-set-for-the-2021-developer-survey-now-available/) appeared on all sites' bulletins, including international sites', even though it never had an aforementioned tag and has all different tags from the one linked in my original post above, and wasn't removed until September 4, 2021.

This seems to be happening randomly with different blog posts, and I can't see a trend with them. They show up in the bulletin for up to a week, before disappearing. Why is this happening? If it's a bug, can it please be fixed?

Comment: I think it should be noted that [you added the `(except on international sites)`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/343846/revisions)

Comment: @dan1st [Source for the above edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/130893/16). My apologies for not linking to it at the time.

Comment: Re *"This blog post is currently featured"*: Perhaps it is time to change to past tense (as if this was written right now)?