# If the OP's username is the width of a comment, the blue box around it extends to the next line

Tags: bug, comments, design, original-poster

I recently noticed that long usernames were triggering something weird ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363449/on-all-sites-the-bulletin-incorrectly-displays-certain-blog-posts-for-24-48-hou#comment1212768_363449)):

[image: highlight box for OP's username extends to a blank line]

A similar case [looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZEv2m.png) on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507070143/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions)

Specifically, when the OP's username is the whole width of the comment field, the blue box highlighting their name extends to the next line, leaving a weird blank space. This was first spotted on my phone and then on my computer.

Computer: Chrome, Windows 10 Home, resolution of 1920x1080 - though I pumped zoom up and squeezed the window to the thinnest it would go, so the picture taken is not at that screen size.
Phone: Chrome, moto g(6), 1080x2160 pixels, responsive website

Comment: There's a lot of [drawbacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317193/character-overflow-on-profile-page-with-long-usernames) to being an anonymous hedgehog...

Comment: Reprod using chrome on huawei P20 pro in the responsive site.

Comment: No repro on [Firefox 91.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3ir8.png), [Firefox 92.0.0-beta.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/005kC.png), [chrome 92.0.4515.166](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drFRY.png), and [Samsung Internet Browser 15.0.2.47 beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyuQR.png).

Comment: Hmmm no repro on chrome on my op9 pro. I suspect screen size is a factor ... So might be useful as part of the bug report

Comment: @JourneymanGeek resolution is 2240*1080 for me

Comment: Luuklang can you tell if you are using web or mobile version in laptop? Also could you share a picture like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIJ5O.png)

Comment: @Rob those images aren't actually what I would expect the bug to look like - the username isn't the width of the comment field, as indicated by text on either side of it. Try zooming in more?

Comment: bobble, Here's maximum zoom, I'd say that the name is [fairly centered within an appropriately sized background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tMmm.png). The previous examples were a bit less than half as much enlargement, but provided the surrounding area; for context / comparison. A [few others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369237/if-the-ops-username-is-the-width-of-a-comment-the-blue-box-around-it-extends-t?noredirect=1#comment1231917_369237) don't see this either, negative findings help the Developer too; to know to check very carefully before declaring the report unfounded.

Comment: @Rob By "zoom" I mean make the text bigger (which is what my browser does for zooming), I'm sorry for using that terminology. Regardless, the point is that if you can't get the username to extend the width of the comment box, the bug won't show up and I don't expect it to.

Comment: bobble, OK, going into my browser's "Accessibility Settings" I see that [I have my "Font Size" set to 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIyYq.png); that is correct, and the default. --- Changing that to a ridiculous [200% font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86PiI.png) and then viewing the result in [Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdFZC.png) **or** [Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0hqh.png) makes **no difference**; the text is correctly centered within an appropriately sized background.

Comment: I can't reproduce this any more, weirdly.