# Is the Stack Exchange Meta site advertised?

Tags: discussion, meta, advertising, community-bulletin, stack-exchange-team

I've noticed that there are a low number of users on Stack Exchange Meta, compared to other SE sites, such as Stack Overflow. Do the Stack Exchange Team ever advertise this site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/what-criteria-are-used-to-select-the-links-that-appear-in-the-community-bulletin)

Comment: It's advertised enough that people come here and post their (off-topic) question intended for other sites here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New features are often written about here, e.g. the [follow feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network). When a question here is marked as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) it appears on all sites in the Featured on Meta area. Every site displays up to two of these questions together with its own site specific [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions. You can find that on the top right of this page.

This is where you see this site's featured questions appear on Stack Overflow for instance:

[image]

We need to be careful with too much advertising though as [this site is for questions about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

- Stack Exchange
- Promotions & Advertising
- Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers [all Stack Exchange websites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

We already get a lot of questions from people who are lost and think this is a good place to ask any question under the sun.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) Meta posts are shown in the sidebar widget on most Q&A pages on **all other sites** in the network:

[image: screenshot of the sidebar widget]

Meta is also featured now and then as 'Today's Featured Site' on the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com):

[image: screenshot of a featured site on the homepage]

Comment: I suspect the last part is a bug, or at least an overlook. (i.e. not intended, since for example Meta is excluded from HNQ).