# Prevent old/cold posts from being listed as hot meta posts

Tags: feature-request, community-bulletin

I noticed a familiar post in the "hot meta posts" panel while on Music Stack Exchange earlier. (It is [the first of the two](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/please-re-open-what-is-this-open-vertical-rectangular-symbol?cb=1) in this screenshot, asking for a post to be re-opened.) But when I went to see what the new activity was, I found the post hadn't been active for a week.

The question had already been re-opened even longer ago, before I had first seen it.

Can we review the criteria for what constitutes a hot post? My suggestion would be to include "active today" as the bare minimum. If there are no hot posts, then in my view it would be preferable to say "No hot posts" than to link to old posts.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The rules for this are listed [in a post here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/what-criteria-are-used-to-select-the-links-that-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/130893#130893) -

> - If there are still under four items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked with any moderator status tag, scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. (Note that the timing, score and tags [can be adjusted per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community).

I understand that it can get frustrating to see the same content for a longer period of time but two weeks isn't that much longer than what you're suggesting. If the post is actually handled, feel free to flag for a mod to add the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, which will kick it out of the hot meta posts list, as noted in the explanation above.