# Only meta questions with both [feature-request] and [discussion] meta tags are featured in Hot Meta Posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin

After [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406461/792066) was introduced, only posts with both [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tags are being featured in the community bulletin. The change says that any of the two tags should be featured. Removing either tag de-features the post. While, adding the tags again doesn't seem to re-add it, as I waited for the next clock hour, afterwards it appeared again.

These two posts demonstrate the behavior:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/406525/revisions
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/406539/revisions

Comment: We're looking into this. Depending on how complicated it is, we may roll it back to discussion only for a bit until we can figure out why it's requiring both instead of either.

Comment: @Catija it seems that adding the tag alone could have triggered the readdition, or not. It's back to the CB.

Comment: For context to others: this bug arose when the team [decided to also include feature requests in the eligible posts for Hot Meta Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406461/2157772), whereas previously, it only included discussions. However, as noted here, the system is incorrectly checking for *both* tags instead of *either or*.

Comment: Looks like the API Docs confirm that adding multiple tags counts as an "and" rather than an "or", so Adam is going to roll this back in the short term until we can figure out the correct solution.

Comment: @Catija maybe you need the same query twice, one for each tag. The CB already have the magic to prevent duplicate items being shown.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for working through this with me so we could identify the issue - as was expected, the API implements multiple tags as an "and" rather than an "or", which means that it was totally [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) that this behaved this way - that said, it's definitely not the intended result.

Since digging into making this work as we intend will take a bit more time, Adam has rolled back the change for the time being and we'll be looking into a fix that will allow both [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tags to be selected simultaneously without requiring both tags in the future.

Comment: Did you check my suggestion in the comments? [According to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/213575) there should be a check to not feature the same post twice.

Comment: @Braiam We didn't have time to look at it - the goal was to just get a quick fix. But when we do dig, we'll look.

Comment: In SO I'm seeing that only the top scored posts are featured. Is the randomness not there in the old implementation?