# Not all posts featured here show up in the community bulletin on all sites, by-design or a bug?

Tags: support, blog, community-bulletin, featured-tag

Currently the community bulletin is filled with at most 4 posts according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/361484). Which also states:

> **Additionally**, up to two [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeatured%5D+is%3Aquestion+created%3A14d..) will appear in the community bulletins of *all* network sites (including Meta Stack Exchange, but not per-site metas). These are also filed under "Featured on Meta". Note that these will appear in addition to all of the other stuff listed above, so the list of community bulletin posts might appear longer than usual, depending on the individual site circumstances.

Currently MSE has 3 featured posts. Which would in theory prevent one of those from showing on the community bulletin (as only 2 are allowed). To solve this for the time being the limit was [temporarily raised to 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views#comment1225066_367609).

This works for all sites that don't show the blog posts, for example [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions). However site's that do show blogposts on their community bulletin, only show 2 posts that are featured here on MSE. For example SO and [3d printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/).

Is this the intended behaviour from the community bulletin, or does the blog section cause issues in this case?