# Does the [featured] tag prevent a post from becoming Hot Meta Post?

Tags: support, community-bulletin, featured-tag, moderator-tags

This answer posted by Shog9 lists how a post becomes a Hot Meta post: [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621#130893) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/130893/30)). Among the conditions listed there, it says that a post tagged with a moderator status tag will not become a hot meta post. But the tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) isn't mentioned there.

**Question:** Does the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag prevent a post from becoming a Hot Meta Post?

---

I can imagine that the developers might have decided to do this - in order to prevent a post from appearing in the community bulletin twice (once as a featured post and a second time as a hot meta post). But if it is the case, probably it would be nice to include this information in the post documenting how the hot meta posts (and the community bulletin) works. (Of course, the other possibility could be to give the post "hot" status - but when selecting entries into the community bulletin, check that no post appears there twice.)

Recently there was this post on MathOverflow Meta: [Upcoming election announcement (2022)](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5427). Neither the [timeline](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/5427/timeline) nor the [revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/5427/revisions) list it as a hot meta post. As far as I can tell, it fulfills the criteria described in the current revision of the linked answer.

Using a [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) query, I found [three posts on Meta Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1532024/hnqs-in-a-specific-tag?tagname=featured) that are both [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and, at the same time, the posthistory includes becoming a hot post. And [one of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419586/revisions) was first tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and then became a hot meta post.
(So in that particular instance, this tag did not prevent the post from becoming hot.) At the moment, I do not have time to create a networkwide query searching for similar things on all per-site-metas. The linked query only shows the posts which have the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) in SEDE at the moment - maybe including a similar query for posts which had such tag in the past could be interesting, too.

Here is another recent instance of a question on Meta Stack Overflow which [became a hot meta post while it was tagged (featured)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/420051/revisions).

Comment: As that post says, hot meta posts are selected randomly from questions on the "Hot" tab on the per-site meta that meet certain criteria. "Not be tagged [tag:featured]" is not one of those criteria, or at least it wasn't at the time it was updated. It does say later on that the overall list is checked for duplicate items before it's rendered, so I think that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I have overlooked the part about duplicates. Still the [revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/5427/revisions) (and the timeline) should show "became hot meta post" - the same way it does on the [example from SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419586/revisions). (I will add the the post from meta MO [is on the hot tab](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/?tab=hot).)