# Isn't the "Community Bulletin" deployed in all the sites?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

I thought that the "Community Bulletin" was deployed on all the sites, but I see that *English Language & Usage* is still using the old block.

[image: screenshot]

Is this intentional, or does the block need to be enabled on every single site?

Comment: [According to Laura](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129559/153008), it's not deployed everywhere yet. A network-wide rollout will occur within 6–8 weeks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now enabled... *Everywhere.*